# How to make popup form when enter and leave object? C#

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I am working on fitness project and need to creat a form with gif over text, when mouse is pointed on it and close popup when mouse leave it. In my case it works only one time. When pointing second time it returnes `System.ObjectDisposedException "Access to the liquidated object is not possible"`

Here is a code with text

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Power : Form
    {
        public Power()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public PopupDemo PopupDemo = null;

        private void guna2CheckBox1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StartPopupDemo();
        }

        private void guna2CheckBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                PopupDemo.Close();
        }

        private void StartPopupDemo()
        {
            int MouseX = Cursor.Position.X;
            int MouseY = Cursor.Position.Y;
            PopupDemo = new PopupDemo();
            PopupDemo.Show();
            PopupDemo.Location = new Point(MouseX - PopupDemo.Width / 2, MouseY - PopupDemo.Height - 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Also i used nuget packages named Guna.

And ther is popup code

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class PopupDemo : Form
    {
        public PopupDemo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    }
}
```

I hope there is more appropriate command instead of `Close()`.
Help pls. If needed something else, just tell me. [This is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvra4.png)

Comment: Which line throws the exception?  If it's `PopupDemo.Close();` then check for null first.  I would avoid using the variable name the same as the class name.  Probably shouldn't be public, and named `popupDemo` to follow standardized casing rules.

Comment: See my two form project.  You need to disable the 2nd form close event.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the behavior but it works as it should be. When mouse hovers over checkbox, the form `PopupDemo` is created and showed. When mouse leaves control, the form is closed. I'm using VS 2017 and Net Frx 4.0. If you don't want to close the form, hide it (method `Hide();`), but then must change the method in `StartPopupDemo()` to create the form once and show it next time.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of u, it was really usefull. And thanks @aamartin2k. Hide(); is working perfectly.